# SQL query does not give distinct value and other issues

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

)

I am making a SQL query to display a high score list of several users scores per user, that also should give a avarage stars the specific user have achived, and the MAX level reached, and also I would like to make a calculation of the total time the user has spent in the game by summing all the time per levels..

**I have the following issues:**

1 : My SQL Query does not give me one line per user.

2 : The sums that are ginving is not per user but a sum of all users.

3 : The avarage STARS are not displaying with decimal.

4 : I cannot get the "score.time_spent" to calculate the sum of all the time the specific user has been playing

**My SQL Query at pressent time is looking like this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
game_users.username AS 'User Name',
'Level Reached' = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(score.game_level) FROM score
        WHERE score.game_users_id IN
        (SELECT game_users_id FROM game_users
        WHERE game_users.id = score.game_users_id)),
score.time_spent AS 'Total Time Spent',
'Stars' = (SELECT DISTINCT AVG(score.stars) FROM score
        WHERE score.game_users_id IN
        (SELECT game_users_id FROM game_users
        WHERE game_users.id = score.game_users_id)),
'High Score' = (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(score.game_level_score) FROM score
        WHERE score.game_users_id IN
        (SELECT game_users_id FROM game_users
        WHERE game_users.id = score.game_users_id)),
game_users.current_state AS 'Online State'          
FROM
game_users
INNER JOIN score ON game_users.id = score.game_users_id
GROUP BY
game_users.id,
game_users.username,
score.game_level_score,
score.game_level,
score.time_spent,
score.stars,
game_users.current_state
GO
```

**The "game_users" table looks like this:**

```
id                      int     Unchecked
firstname       varchar(100)    Checked
lastname        varchar(100)    Checked
email           varchar(100)    Checked
username        varchar(50)     Checked
usr_pass        varchar(50)     Checked
current_state           int     Checked
```

**The "score" table looks like this:**

```
id                         int      Unchecked
game_users_id              int      Unchecked
game_level          varchar(4)      Checked
game_level_score    numeric(18, 0)  Checked
stars                      int      Checked
time_spent             time(7)      Checked
```

Can someone help me out in this mess? :-)

Best Regards

Stig :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this should solve it:

```
SELECT a.username AS 'User Name'
    , MAX(b.game_level) AS 'Level Reached'
    , CAST(DATEADD(millisecond,SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond,0,CAST(b.time_spent AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) AS 'Total Time Spent'
    , AVG(CAST(b.stars AS FLOAT)) AS 'Stars'
    , SUM(b.game_level_score) AS 'High Score'
    , a.current_state AS 'Online State'
FROM game_users a
JOIN score b
    ON a.id = b.game_users_id
GROUP BY a.username, a.current_state
```

Note: the CAST line is from this site - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=121027

EDIT: Casted stars as float.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer :-) Norla, you have 100% solved all the issues, I could actually just copy/paste the script, and it works BRILLIANT! 

Thank you so much :-)

/Stig :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing your aggregates in a subquery. I am not sure if this is exactly what you require but it should set you in the right direction:

```
SELECT  Game_Users.userName,
        MaxLevel,
        TimeSpent,
        Stars,
        HighScore,
        Game_Users.Current_State [Online State]
FROM    game_users
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Game_users_ID, 
                    MAX(Game_Level) [MaxLevel], 
                    AVG(Stars * 1.0) [Stars], 
                    SUM(game_level_Score) [HighScore],
                    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))) [TimeSpent]
            FROM    Score
            GROUP BY Game_Users_ID
        ) score
            ON score.Game_Users_ID = game_users.ID
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answer :-) Norla, you have 100% solved all the issues, I could actually just copy/paste the script, and it works BRILLIANT! 

Thank you so much :-)

/Stig :-)